# Pandas - Merge multiple columns and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a main `df` like so:

```
index   A  B  C
5       1  5  8
6       2  4  1
7       8  3  4
8       3  9  5
```

and an auxiliary `df2` that I want to add to the main df like so:

```
index   A  B  
5       4  2 
6       4  3 
7       7  1 
8       6  2
```

Columns A & B are the same name, however the main `df` contains many columns that the secondary `df2` does not. I want to sum the columns that are common and leave the others as is.

Output:

```
index   A  B  C
5       5  7  8
6       6  7  1
7       15 4  4
8       9  11 5
```

Have tried variations of `df.join`, `pd.merge` and `groupby` but having no luck at the moment.

Last Attempt:

```
df.groupby('index').sum().add(df2.groupby('index').sum())
```

But this does not keep common columns.

`pd.merge` I am getting suffix `_x` and `_y`

Comment: Is possible `index` values are duplicated?

Comment: No, all unique.

Comment: In your case `(df1+df2).fillna(df1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) only with same columns by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
c = df.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
df[c] = df[c].add(df2[c], fill_value=0)
print (df)
        A   B  C
index           
5       5   7  8
6       6   7  1
7      15   4  4
8       9  11  5
```

If use only `add`, integers columns which not matched are converted to `float`s:

```
df = df.add(df2, fill_value=0)
print (df)
        A   B    C
index             
5       5   7  8.0
6       6   7  1.0
7      15   4  4.0
8       9  11  5.0
```

EDIT:

If possible strings common columns:

```
print (df)
       A  B  C  D
index            
5      1  5  8  a
6      2  4  1  e
7      8  3  4  r
8      3  9  5  w
print (df2)
       A  B  C  D
index            
5      1  5  8  a
6      2  4  1  e
7      8  3  4  r
8      3  9  5  w
```

Solution is similar, only filter first only numeric columns by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
c = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns.intersection(df2.select_dtypes(np.number).columns)
df[c] = df[c].add(df2[c], fill_value=0)
print (df)
        A   B  C  D
index              
5       5   7  8  a
6       6   7  1  e
7      15   4  4  r
8       9  11  5  w
```

Comment: Fantastic, the aforementioned answer used a list of common columns, which is quite prohibitive with a large `df`. The intersection is a very elegant way around that, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Not the cleanest way but it might work.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['A'] = df['A'] + df2['A']
df_new['B'] = df['B'] + df2['B']
df_new['C'] = df['C']


print(df_new)

    A   B  C
0   5   7  8
1   6   7  1
2  15   4  4
3   9  11  5
```

Comment: It can cause errors, what if two df not sharing same indexes ?